# ontouchend ios returns wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, html5-canvas

I've been reading the very helpful book 'Core HTML5 Canvas', and it includes a sample of including mouseclicks and touches in the same function.  My version of it (very similar to the book) is as follows:

```
function windowToCanvas(x, y) {
    var bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    return { x: x - bbox.left * (canvas.width /bbox.width), y: y - bbox.top * (canvas.height / bbox.height)};
};

canvas.ontouchstart = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    MTStart(windowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY));
};

canvas.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    MTMove(windowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY));
};

canvas.ontouchend = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    MTEnd(windowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY));
};

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    MTStart(windowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY));
};

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    MTMove(windowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY));
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    MTEnd(windowToCanvas(e.pageX, e.pageY));
};

function MTStart(location) {
    console.log("Mouse down");
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'MT Start x: ' + location.x + ', y: ' + location.y;
};

function MTMove(location) {

};

function MTEnd(location) {
    console.log("Mouse up");
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'MT End x: ' + location.x + ', y: ' + location.y;
};
```

This works fine with the mouse.  However, running on safari on iphone or ipad, the ontouchstart seems to report the correct location, while ontouchend does not.  Ontouchend will give the same coordinates regardless of where I touch.  I noticed that the coordinates it returns seem to change if and only if I scroll the page a bit and touch the same location within the canvas.

Any idea why ontouchstart and ontouchend would be giving different location values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that I need to use:

```
MTEnd(windowToCanvas(e.changedTouches[0].pageX, e.changedTouches[0].pageY));
```

But only for the ontouchend, and not ontouchstart.